# How to extract data from an interactive graph

Tags: python, r, json, web-scraping, interactive

I need to fetch datapoints from the [website](https://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2020/president/us/2020_democratic_presidential_nomination-6730.html) that provides aggregated polling number. The data was presented in an interactive graph. How should I fetch all the data points (date:number pair)for every candidate? I have tried to analyze and inspect the source code but couldn't find the data file it points to. I will be comfortable with solutions either in Python or R. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You say you checked for a data file, have you checked for an API call? That’s the most likely source IMO.

Comment: I agree, and I have suspected it too. But didn't know 1. how to check API call and 2. I am not sure how to fetch the file after locating the call...Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: For finding the API call, your best bet is going to be using your browser’s developer tools (or whatever they call them) to monitor network requests. That’s browser-specific though, so you’ll have to find out yourself. Part 2 is a bit more complex. If they are just grabbing a file, that should be fine. If it is an API call proper, you’ll have to find out how it’s called, and do so yourself. How difficult that is depends entirely on the website. I can take a look myself, but not until tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated above, find the API call in dev tools. Then its just a matter of getting the response and manipulate it as needed:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
import time


timestamp = str(int(time.time()*1000.0))

url ='https://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/json/6730_historical.js'

headers = {
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Mobile Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
timestamp: '',
'callback': 'return_json'}


jsonStr = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).text
jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr.split('(',1)[-1].rsplit(')',1)[0])

results = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['poll']['rcp_avg'])
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(row['candidate'])
    temp_df['date'] = row['date']
    results = results.append(temp_df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results)
     affiliation    color                date  ...        name status value
0                 #009900 2019-11-28 06:00:00  ...       Biden      1  27.0
1                 #457fff 2019-11-28 06:00:00  ...     Sanders      1  18.3
2                 #996600 2019-11-28 06:00:00  ...      Warren      1  15.8
3                 #990099 2019-11-28 06:00:00  ...   Buttigieg      1  11.0
4                 #ff9900 2019-11-28 06:00:00  ...      Harris      1   3.8
5                 #3da882 2019-11-28 06:00:00  ...        Yang      1   3.3
6                 #f2dc0f 2019-11-28 06:00:00  ...   Bloomberg      1   2.5
7                 #000000 2019-11-28 06:00:00  ...   Klobuchar      1   2.2
8                 #66ccff 2019-11-28 06:00:00  ...      Booker      1   1.8
9                 #666666 2019-11-28 06:00:00  ...      Steyer      1   1.7
10                #ff0074 2019-11-28 06:00:00  ...     Gabbard      1   1.3
11                #cc9900 2019-11-28 06:00:00  ...      Castro      1   1.2
12                #9966ff 2019-11-28 06:00:00  ...      Bennet      1   0.6
13                #10671b 2019-11-28 06:00:00  ...     Bullock      3   0.4
14                #990000 2019-11-28 06:00:00  ...     Patrick      3   0.4
15                #6672ff 2019-11-28 06:00:00  ...      Sestak      3   0.3
16                #009900 2019-11-27 06:00:00  ...       Biden      1  28.2
17                #457fff 2019-11-27 06:00:00  ...     Sanders      1  17.8
18                #996600 2019-11-27 06:00:00  ...      Warren      1  16.7
19                #990099 2019-11-27 06:00:00  ...   Buttigieg      1  10.5
20                #ff9900 2019-11-27 06:00:00  ...      Harris      1   3.8
21                #3da882 2019-11-27 06:00:00  ...        Yang      1   3.2
22                #f2dc0f 2019-11-27 06:00:00  ...   Bloomberg      1   2.4
23                #000000 2019-11-27 06:00:00  ...   Klobuchar      1   2.0
24                #66ccff 2019-11-27 06:00:00  ...      Booker      1   1.7
25                #666666 2019-11-27 06:00:00  ...      Steyer      1   1.7
26                #ff0074 2019-11-27 06:00:00  ...     Gabbard      1   1.5
27                #cc9900 2019-11-27 06:00:00  ...      Castro      1   1.0
28                #9966ff 2019-11-27 06:00:00  ...      Bennet      1   0.8
29                #10671b 2019-11-27 06:00:00  ...     Bullock      3   0.4
         ...      ...                 ...  ...         ...    ...   ...
5650              #996600 2018-12-10 06:00:00  ...      Warren      1   6.0
5651              #990099 2018-12-10 06:00:00  ...   Buttigieg      1   NaN
5652              #ff9900 2018-12-10 06:00:00  ...      Harris      1   5.3
5653              #3da882 2018-12-10 06:00:00  ...        Yang      1   NaN
5654              #f2dc0f 2018-12-10 06:00:00  ...   Bloomberg      1   NaN
5655              #000000 2018-12-10 06:00:00  ...   Klobuchar      1   NaN
5656              #66ccff 2018-12-10 06:00:00  ...      Booker      1   4.0
5657              #666666 2018-12-10 06:00:00  ...      Steyer    NaN   NaN
5658              #ff0074 2018-12-10 06:00:00  ...     Gabbard      1   NaN
5659              #cc9900 2018-12-10 06:00:00  ...      Castro      1   NaN
5660              #9966ff 2018-12-10 06:00:00  ...      Bennet      1   NaN
5661              #10671b 2018-12-10 06:00:00  ...     Bullock      3   NaN
5662              #990000 2018-12-10 06:00:00  ...     Patrick    NaN   NaN
5663              #6672ff 2018-12-10 06:00:00  ...      Sestak    NaN   NaN
5664              #009900 2018-12-09 06:00:00  ...       Biden      1  29.0
5665              #457fff 2018-12-09 06:00:00  ...     Sanders      1  17.7
5666              #996600 2018-12-09 06:00:00  ...      Warren      1   6.0
5667              #990099 2018-12-09 06:00:00  ...   Buttigieg      1   NaN
5668              #ff9900 2018-12-09 06:00:00  ...      Harris      1   5.3
5669              #3da882 2018-12-09 06:00:00  ...        Yang      1   NaN
5670              #f2dc0f 2018-12-09 06:00:00  ...   Bloomberg      1   NaN
5671              #000000 2018-12-09 06:00:00  ...   Klobuchar      1   NaN
5672              #66ccff 2018-12-09 06:00:00  ...      Booker      1   4.0
5673              #666666 2018-12-09 06:00:00  ...      Steyer    NaN   NaN
5674              #ff0074 2018-12-09 06:00:00  ...     Gabbard      1   NaN
5675              #cc9900 2018-12-09 06:00:00  ...      Castro      1   NaN
5676              #9966ff 2018-12-09 06:00:00  ...      Bennet      1   NaN
5677              #10671b 2018-12-09 06:00:00  ...     Bullock      3   NaN
5678              #990000 2018-12-09 06:00:00  ...     Patrick    NaN   NaN
5679              #6672ff 2018-12-09 06:00:00  ...      Sestak    NaN   NaN

[5680 rows x 7 columns]
```

As you can see, when you chart this, it will look like the the graph on the site:

```
# Convert columns to appropriate type to chart
results['value'] = results['value'].astype(float)
results['date'] = pd.to_datetime(results['date']) 

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
palette = pd.Series(results.color.values,index=results.name).to_dict()

sns.lineplot(data=results, x="date", y="value", hue="name", palette=palette)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you (and Alexander as well!) very much! Answer accepted. It worked perfectly. Could you explain what payload is doing here? It seems that's a key step. Thanks again!

Comment: when you look at the dev tools, you can see that theres a query form that sometimes is needed to use to get a desired return. To be hones, not sure it matters in this case, but included it anyways

Comment: Yes, I think I found the query with the inspect option of Chrome. Thanks again!